# Add new array in embedded array field by fetching max value + 1 from existing array embedded field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Below is the structure of my Collection.

```
{
  "_id": "61b70e9d7ba0e2a555e06a59",
  "ProjId": 12,
  "ArtifactAttributes": [
    {
      "_t": "ArtifactAttributes",
      "AttrId": 1,
      "AttributeName": "Description",
      "AttributeValue": "Test Description"
    },
    {
      "_t": "ArtifactAttributes",
      "AttrId": 2,
      "AttributeName": "Details",
      "AttributeValue": "Test Details"
    }
  ]
}
```

I wanted to add below mentioned array in the `ArtifactAttributes` array field present in the collection but while adding the same wanted to set `AttrId` by fetching max value + 1 of `AttrId` present in the existing array list.

AttrId is totally dependents on the max value of the `AttrId` present in the existing array it could 3,4,5 anything.

```
{
      "_t": "ArtifactAttributes",
      "AttrId": 3,
      "AttributeName": "Owner",
      "AttributeValue": "Test Owner"
    }
```

Final document after adding above array will be as below

```
{
  "_id": "61b70e9d7ba0e2a555e06a59",
  "ProjId": 12,
  "ArtifactAttributes": [
    {
      "_t": "ArtifactAttributes",
      "AttrId": 1,
      "AttributeName": "Description",
      "AttributeValue": "Test Description"
    },
    {
      "_t": "ArtifactAttributes",
      "AttrId": 2,
      "AttributeName": "Details",
      "AttributeValue": "Test Details"
    },
    {
      "_t": "ArtifactAttributes",
      "AttrId": 3,
      "AttributeName": "Owner",
      "AttributeValue": "Test Owner"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried around a little bit, to use $push or $addField does not work, so I came up with concatinating 2 arrays where I define your object as an object of the 2nd array for concatination.

So simplified:
Set the Array you allready have, as a concatination of that array with a new array containing your object with calculated AttrId of the other arrays AttrId.

I directly added the function into the object you want to insert:

```js
let toBeInserted = {
      "_t": "ArtifactAttributes",
      "AttributeName": "Owner",
      "AttributeValue": "Test Owner"
    }
    // If you are using typescript make sure AttrId is previously unset 
    // because it will throw an error if it wants to insert this into a "number" field
    toBeInserted["AttrId"] = {
      '$add': [{ '$max': '$ArtifactAttributes.AttrId' }, 1]
    }
    await this.testSchema.updateOne({}, // Make sure the following is an array, array indicates aggregation, this does not work without
      [{
        '$set': {
          'ArtifactAttributes': {
            '$concatArrays': [
              '$ArtifactAttributes', [
                toBeInserted
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      }])
```

Here proof of it working:
[image]